# React Redux - Setting Store and Updating UI using Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm extremely new to react/redux and very mediocre at Javascript, but I've been struggling with this for over a week now. Here's what I'm trying to do:
[image: Rough mock-up]
Clicking one of the navigation menu items on the left should dispatch an action to set the selected index in the store (at this point the entire store is just a number). When the index is updated it should automatically be reflected in the UI, at least by changing the css class of the selected item, but eventually it should toggle visibility for content components on the right.

**Sidebar.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SidebarItem from './SidebarItem'
import ActionCreators from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export default class Sidebar extends Component
{   
    handleClick(index)
    {
        //Dispatch action here maybe?
        this.props.selectedSidebarItem(index);
        console.log(this);
    }
    render()
    {
        var sidebarItemNames = ["Verify Original Contract", "Evaluate Transfer Terms", "Create Future Customer", "Check Credit", "Generate Agreement", "Finalize Transfer"];
        return (            
                <div>
                    <div id="sidebar-title">
                        <div id="sc-logo">
                            LOGO
                        </div>
                        <div>Contract Transfer for:</div>
                        <div>XYZ</div>
                        <br />                  
                    </div>                                      
                    <ul className="list-group" id="sidebar-list">
                        {sidebarItemNames.map(function(n, index)
                        {
                            return <SidebarItem key={index} index={index} selectedIndex={this.selectedSidebarItem} name={n} handleClick={this.handleClick(index).bind(this)} />;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    selectedSidebarItem: (index) => dispatch(ActionCreators.setSelectedSidebarItem(index))
  }
}
const conn = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Sidebar)
```

**SidebarItem.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ActionCreators from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export class SidebarItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    setSelectedSidebarItem() {
        this.props.handleClick(this.props.index);
        this.props.selectedSidebarItem(this.props.index);    
        // const ul = document.getElementById('sidebar-list');
        // const items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
        // for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        //     items[i].classList.remove('sidebar-item-current');
        // }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li className={"list-group-item sidebar-list-item sidebar-item-todo" + (this.props.index==this.props.selectedIndex? ' sidebar-item-current':'') } onClick={this.setSelectedSidebarItem.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> <span>{this.props.name}</span></li>
        )
    }
}
```

**Store.js:**
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import reducers from './Reducers'

```
const store = createStore(reducers)

export default store
```

**Reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
    selectedSidebarItem: window.initialPageState,
    otherStuff: 5
};
const reducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SELECTED_SIDEBAR_ITEM":
        console.log("clicked sidebar index: " + action.index);
            var result = Object.assign({}, state, {
                selectedSidebarItem: action.index
            })
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducers
```

**actions.js:**

```
import constants from './constants'

let ActionCreators = {
    setSelectedSidebarItem(index) {
        var actionObject = {
            type: constants.UPDATE_SELECTED_SIDEBAR_ITEM,
            index
        }
        console.log("setting sidebar item", actionObject);

        return actionObject
    }
}
export default ActionCreators
```

**Constants.js**

```
const constants = { 
    UPDATE_SELECTED_SIDEBAR_ITEM: "UPDATE_SELECTED_SIDEBAR_ITEM",
    ADD_ERROR: "ADD_ERROR",
    CLEAR_ERROR: "CLEAR_ERROR"
};

export default constants;
```

I've tried a few variations of the above and have previously been able to dispatch actions, but am unsure the store is ever updated and nothing is reflected on the UI. Right now I'm getting this error when clicking sidebar items: "Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined"

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Am now getting this error:
"app.bundle.js:22790 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedSidebarItem is not defined"

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your sidebar.js:
instead of

```
handleClick={() => this.handleClick(index).bind(this)}
```

try this:

```
handleClick={this.handleClick(index).bind(this)}
```

And in `handleClick` method you have to dispatch action:

```
this.props.selectedSidebarItem(index)
```

Answer update:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SidebarItem from './SidebarItem'
import ActionCreators from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export default class Sidebar extends Component
{   
    handleClick(index)
    {
        //Dispatch action here maybe?
        this.props.selectedSidebarItem(index);
        this.selectedSidebarItem = index;
        console.log(this);
    }
    render()
    {
        var sidebarItemNames = ["Verify Original Contract", "Evaluate Transfer Terms", "Create Future Customer", "Check Credit", "Generate Agreement", "Finalize Transfer"];
        return (            
                <div>
                    <div id="sidebar-title">
                        <div id="sc-logo">
                            LOGO
                        </div>
                        <div>Contract Transfer for:</div>
                        <div>XYZ</div>
                        <br />                  
                    </div>                                      
                    <ul className="list-group" id="sidebar-list">
                        {sidebarItemNames.map(function(n, index)
                        {
                            return <SidebarItem key={index} index={index} selectedIndex={this.selectedSidebarItem} name={n} handleClick={this.handleClick(index).bind(this)} />;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    selectedSidebarItem: (index) => dispatch(ActionCreators.setSelectedSidebarItem(index))
  }
}
const conn = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Sidebar)
```

---

Comment: Thanks, this helps, I have updated my post to reflect the change

Comment: Still getting same error after update "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedSidebarItem is not defined." I tried setting this value in the Sidebar's constructor, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You have to update `handleClick` method body accroding to my answer in sidebar.js. In your example it's still wrong

Comment: I did that and am now getting "Cannot read property 'selectedSidebarItem' of undefined"

Comment: because this variable is not defined and you try to pass it down to SidebarItem component. Generally I think that you should disptach actions in Sidebar component and SidebarItem can be only presentational component

Comment: Thanks, but I tried replacing the Sidebar code your updated answer but still getting same error. I also tried setting a property "selectedSidebarItem" with a default value of 0. But then I get error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" when attempting to pass in selectedIndex={this.props.selectedSidebarItem}